# Chrome apps: запуск без лаунчера

Tags: google-chrome, app, chrome-app

Есть специальный лаунчер для приложений chrome. Но я не считаю его удобным. Можно ли запустить приложение chrome без лаунчера? Как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запустите Google Chrome с параметром `--app-id=<id-вашего приложения>`.

Можете просто нажать в лаунчере правой кнопкой на необходимом приложении, выбрать "создать ярлык", после чего запускать приложение используя этот самый ярлык(либо посмотреть параметры в свойствах, и указать их в своём коде).

Comment: Спасибо! Id, который указан на странице расширений?

Comment: @egordorichev, да, оттуда.